# How can I change notify-osd behaviour? (14.04)

Tags: notification, 14.04, notify-osd

I want to know if it's still possible to change the `notify-osd` behavior. I used `notifyosdconf` in Ubuntu 13.10. but it doesn't work after the new install.

I checked the files mentioned in the [file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/amd64/notify-osd/filelist) but didn't find a configuration file. Changing `.notify-osd` in my home folder did not change anything as well (I'm not sure if it was created by `notifyosdconf`).

I Just want to close the bubbles if I click on them.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just installed NotifyOSD on 14.04 and it works.

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/closable-movable-notifyosd.html
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/configurable-notifyosd-updated-for.html

Comment: Didn't work for me until there was an update a few days ago. Thank you anyways!